# Read only some lines of a large File

Tags: ruby, file

I have a large text file (56MB, 7500000 lines). I get an `OutofMemory` error if I read the entire file at once. I want to read 20000 lines at a time, do stuff, and then continue. How can I read 20000 lines starting from a specific line?

Comment: It's always best to show your work, here, so we aren't guessing as to what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

[IO#each_line](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line) is your friend.

```
file = File.new('filename', 'r') # or whatever
file.each_line do |line|
  # do something with a line
end
```

It will read lines efficiently, not loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: the problem here is that till line 150000 it goes fast but then slows down and outofmemory

Comment: Hm, do you have a memory leak in there? `each_line` alone should work just fine.

Comment: You might want to display what you are doing in the each_line do loop.  If you are simply loading them into an array or something, you will experience the results you describe.  The intent of this construct as written is to process one line at a time and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

This code fits your need, reading in a series of max lines, processing them, clearing them and looping through eof.  Resetting the array is the key to eliminating OutofMemory conditions.

```
class ReadLoop

  lines = Array.new       # Array to hold the next series of lines
  count = 0               # Count of lines read into the current series
  max = 3                 # Maximum number of lines

  file = File.new('yourfilenamehere', 'r') # or whatever

  file.each_line do |line|
    count += 1
    lines << line
    if count == max || file.eof
      then
        puts "Next series of lines:"
        puts lines
        count = 0
        lines = Array.new
    end
  end
end
```

An alternative answer that directly answers your question is to use gets (each_line) and lineno.  Querying lineno tells you the number of times gets has been called.  Setting lineno manually sets the current line number to the given value.  The reference is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-ioctl).  You can try adding "puts file.lineno" within the loop above to see how it works.

Comment: Any progress?  Did this help?

Comment: Did this solve your problem?  If not, do you have questions?  If yes, can you please accept it?  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... use simple unix commands. For instance **sed** from 5000 to 10000 lines

```
%x{sed -n 5000,10000p ./file_you_want}.each_line do |line|
  # do with lines
end
```